AppSync custom mutations that calls multiple mutations
I have a custom mutation that calls multiple mutation
mutation saveVotes {
  vote1: saveVotes(author: "AUTHORNAME", value: 1 ) { author, value }
  vote2: saveVotes(author: "AUTHORNAME", value: 3 ) { author, value }
}

With this, is it possible for only the vote1 to execute while vote2 fails because i need both of them to act as if they were a transaction but at the same time benefit from each's subscription? I couldn't find anything from the documentation relating to this.
